# Mongoose query doesn't return an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, coffeescript, mongoose

I am messing aroung with mongoose and I am simply trying to return an object that is in my collection (which to my understanding is  the equivalent of a row that is in an SQL table).

In the video I am watching it says that all callbacks from mongoose return error and results but I am only able to return the results never an error (logs as undefined) even when I force an error nothing happens.

How do I find out when I have an error?

here is the code I have.

```
app = require("../server")
dashboard = require("../models/dashboard")

app.get('/request', (req, res)->
  dashboard.users.find({}).exec().then (users, err) ->
    console.log err
    res.send users
)
```

The 2nd parameter always comes out undefined no matter what I name it. Also this is written in coffeescript I'll have a javascript version below

```
var app, dashboard;
app = require("../server");
dashboard = require("../models/dashboard");
app.get('/request', function(req, res) {
  return dashboard.users.find({}).exec().then(function(users, err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.send(users);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>The *first* argument being passed to the callback is the error:</s>

```
dashboard.users.find({}).exec().then (err, users) ->
  etc...
```

Never mind my first answer, I only just noticed that you're using promises, which work different from "regular" callbacks.

With regular callbacks, the first argument passed is always the error value (or `null` when no error occurred), and the following arguments are result arguments (usually just one, sometimes more than one).

Promises work differently, with two functions:

```
.then(
  function(results) { ... },
  function(err) { ... }
)
```

The first function will be called when the operation (in this case, the `find`) was succesful. The second function will be called when an error occurred.

Comment: even when i reverse it the 2nd argument is undefined no matter what i do, also if the first argument is error why does it return my the results then?

Comment: @grasshopper if the 2nd argument is always undefined, what do you mean by "why does it return my results"? Those statements seem to contradict each other.

Comment: it returns the results of the query, so instead of getting an error message I get everything in my collection

Comment: @grasshopper why would you expect an error to occur?

Comment: I expect the error because like you said the error is the **first argument** so it should return "null" and the **second argument** should return the results of the query if the function was successful. This is not what happens though, no matter what I name the first argument it will return the result of my query.